# clean invalid GCM device keys android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How to clean invalid GCM device keys? I use the code below to send, but, I see that there are errors like: when I fire a notification, it seems I triggered 10 and 10 notifications arrive in a row. I think the problem is with keys that are no longer valid.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The API key is connected to the signing key. It doesn't have an expiration date but the signing key does. If you use the debug key signing key it will expire after one year. So what you can do is use other API key if it start to not working. Check also this [thread](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/backend-services/javascript/push-notifications/troubleshooting/push-trb-android.html) that will help you to determine the Common Reasons for Failing Push Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

please check your packagename at time of google registration. it should be unique if packagename use in some other google registration it will not work.

Comment: I already checked. is not it. I'm pretty sure it's because of invalid keys. I just wanted to clean them. Because when the user uninstalls the application the key is invalidated. So I would need to know how to know if this key is still in use or not for me to delete from the database. thank you.